# $\Lambda = A^T A$ Decomposition of inverse covariance matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, covariance

Let Precision $\Lambda = S^{-1}$ be defined as inverse covariance matrix. I would like to decompose it as $\Lambda = A^TA$, where $A$ is a square matrix. Covariance and Precision are both positive definite, and all above matrices should be real.

1. How to compute $A$? If $A$ is non-unique, you may introduce any additional constraints to make it unique. The aim is simplicity of computation
2. What is the interpretation of $A$?

Comment: does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition

Comment: Looks good. Is it guaranteed that the elements of $L$ are real?

Comment: A possible interpretation of $A^{-1}$ (not $A$, sorry) is how to transform an i.i.d. Gaussian random vector into a correlated Gaussian random vector with $S$ as covariance .

Comment: The Cholesky factorization is commonly used for this and is unique.

Comment: May I ask again, is $A$ real? I need a decomposition such that I can later use it to transform my data into $y = Ax$. I would like $y$ to be real. Is this guaranteed with Cholesky Decomposition?

Comment: Only if the matrix you're decomposing is positive-semi-definite, which is true here. This is not the only solution, but it is when we require $A$ to be triangular @AleksejsFomins

Comment: @Theorem Thanks, this helps